# Like button in iframe not loading

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

When I use this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FStoneMason-Marble-Granite%2F363939960302642&amp;width&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I don't get any button that shows up. If I remove the id at the end of the facebook page, then I get a button, but a window pops up and closes immediately:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FStoneMason-Marble-Granite&amp;width&amp;height=35&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I've tried turning off my popup blocker, but still closes.